# how to implement diff with perl

Tags: perl, diff

any one may have an idea of realizing the function of "diff" command with perl? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) module [Algorithm::Diff](http://p3rl.org/Algorithm%3a%3aDiff) for computing the difference between two files or lists.

Comment: A bit more higher level modules that build on the Algorithm::Diff foundation are [Text::Diff](http://p3rl.org/Text::Diff), [Text::WordDiff](http://p3rl.org/Text::WordDiff), [String::Diff](http://p3rl.org/String::Diff)

Answer (score 2):

There's a diff in the [Perl Power Tools](http://www.metacpan.org/module/PerlPowerTools) on CPAN.